# how to force a method to infer a generic type

Tags: android, android-fragments, generics, kotlin

in the below code, i have 2 fragments FragmentLeft and FragmentRight both extends from Fragment class.
according to the extenstion methods below, i am trying to use a generic data type as  a parameter to the method, so that when i use this method it should accept either instances of FragmentLeft or FragmentRight.....

however, the code below generates an error stated in the comment

please let me know how to solve it

**code**

```
var fragTransactionInstance = getFragmentManagerInstance()?.let {
        it.getFragmentTransactionInstance()
            ?.replaceTransaction(R.id.fragLeft, fragmentLeft)//no enough 
   information to infer type variable T   
            ?.replaceTransaction(R.id.fragRight, fragmentRight)////no 
   enough information to infer type variable T 
    }?.also {
        it.commit()
    }
  }

fun initViews() : Unit {
    fragmentLeft = FragmentLeft()
    fragmentRight = FragmentRight()
}
fun <T : Fragment> FragmentTransaction.replaceTransaction(layout: Int, t: 
Fragment?): FragmentTransaction {
    return this.replace(layout, t)
}
```

**classes**:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.example.kotlindynmaicfragment_v1.MainActivity
import com.example.kotlindynmaicfragment_v1.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*

class FragmentRight : Fragment() {

val LOG_TAG = this::class.java.name

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate")

}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onActivityCreated")

}

///////////////////
class FragmentLeft : Fragment() {

val LOG_TAG = this::class.java.name

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate")

}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onActivityCreated")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue comes from the fact that you defined your `replaceTransaction` method as generic, but you're not using `T` at all in that method, so type inference doesn't know what type to use in place of `T`.

To give you a simpler example, this will cause the same error:

```
fun <T> foo() {
    println("Hello, world!")
}

fun main() {
    foo()
}
```

That happens because `T` cannot be inferred, so you need to explicitly tell what type to use (even though it's not used at all in `foo`):

```
fun main() {
    foo<Unit>() // I used Unit, but any other type would do
}
```

Given that, do you need `T` at all in your code? Both `FragmentRight` and `FragmentLeft` extend from `Fragment`, so unless you need to use specific functionalities from those classes, you can discard `T` and use the parent type `Fragment` (as you're already doing).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `t:Fragment`, change the type of `t` to `T`, not `Fragment`
Try to write your extension function this way:

```
fun <T : Fragment> FragmentTransaction.replaceTransaction(layout: Int, t: 
T): FragmentTransaction {
    return this.replace(layout, t)
}
```